# My Tcp server is using waaaay too much memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, tcplistener, tcpserver

so I've made a C# TCP server, however whenever I connected multiple clients for a test, the whole device starts to lag out and the memory goes to 500 MB, earlier 1GB. I understand that this has to do with code structure and so however I'm not sure what's really causing this. 
[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJUer.png)
[Console.](https://prnt.sc/iib1ke)

Basically, here's my server class.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Roleplay_Flash_Server.assets.communication
{
    class server
    {
        private static TcpListener serverHandle;
        private const string prefix  = "[communication->server.cs] ";
        private static bool responded = false;

        public static void init(int port)
        {
            serverHandle = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            serverHandle.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting on a client...");

            while (responded == false)
            {
                serverHandle.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, serverHandle);
                //responded = false;
            }
        }

        private static void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult response)
        {
            responded = true;
            serverHandle.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, serverHandle);

            TcpClient client = serverHandle.EndAcceptTcpClient(response);

            communication.client.incoming.connection(client);
            communication.client.events.pingIntervalEvent.init(client);
            communication.client.events.handshakeEvent.init(client);

            while(true)
            {
                string test = readRequest(client);
            }

            destruct(client);
        }

        public static string readRequest(TcpClient socket)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int response = socket.Client.Receive(data);

            if (response == 0) return "";

            string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            string clientPort = ((IPEndPoint)socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString();

            Console.Write(prefix + "Received data from {#" + "?" + "}, {" + clientIP + ":" + clientPort + "}: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, response));
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, response);
        }

        private static void destruct(TcpClient socket)
        {
            string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            string clientPort = ((IPEndPoint)socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString();

            Console.Write(prefix + "Lost connection with {#" + "?" + "}, {" + clientIP + ":" + clientPort + "}.");
            socket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: All classes which may be causing this memory overflow:

https://pastebin.com/eB54fJY2

https://pastebin.com/LW2A7RZk

https://pastebin.com/t9YvTNsj

https://pastebin.com/C18du82K

Comment: I doubt the code allocating the memory is this, it must be outside.

Comment: You're measuring memory when running in the debugger: that adds plenty of overhead. If you run outside the debugger and check the memory (even Task Manager will do for a quick check but performance counters are better) what do you see?

Comment: This is the only class using infinitive loops and I can see the memory physically raising when this class is constructed, going 4 MB or more every ½ seconds. @Gusman

Comment: @Richard even if so, I wouldn't think that the debugger would add an additional gigabyte over its tools? That's an eighth part of my memory.

Comment: Check your code for Disposable objects and make sure you dispose them as appropriate. You can use a memory profiler to help too.

Comment: Inifinite loops aren't causing your problems, the image you have shown of a console is doing something with the clients, this is not the real code, so we can't know where are you allocating resources and if you're freeing those correctly. I would bet you aren't cleaning client resources when a disconnection is happening.

Comment: @Gusman those are pretty much only `Console.Write{Line}` right now but however, adding the other classes on the topic in a sec.

Comment: Images of code are a waste of time, only include the text in the question. If this is too long, reduce until you have a minimal re-create

Comment: You are doing webrequests and aren't disposing anything, that may cause the memory leaks. Dispose everything that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Richard no where have I included screenshots of direct code, what I did provide is two screenshots of: (1) the Console, (2) the debug calculations.

Gusman- thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: You can take a memory dump and explore it using WinDbg/SOS. That'll let you see what objects you have in memory and start to explore why they're lurking around. Debugging tools for windows include WinDbg and some tools for taking memory dumps. Process Explorer is another tool that can create dumps

Comment: You have the tools to troubleshoot this, just learn how to use the memory snapshot feature.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage

Answer (score 0):

So I've fixed this issue by simply removing the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` from the Async callback, this was causing the function to be called in the infinite loop but also in another callback called from the loop, making excessive memory overflow.